# Extrude to Cursor - has no connections between vertices

Tags: extrude, lines

I'm trying to work according to the official manual

The example shows that dots must have a connection when used. but I can't get it to draw a line:

[Extrude to Cursor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/extrude_cursor.html)

my dots look like this. They don't want to connect with each other. I'm sorry, I'm new to blender and don't know much yet.

[video how it works for me](https://www.veed.io/view/53119505-bdd1-4e83-b9f3-ca1961726c35?sharingWidget=true&panel=)

[how i want it to work - 2:39](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcSDF917dBo)

gif if the video link stops working:

[image]

as you can see, points are added, but there are no connections between them

blender file:

[image]

Comment: The image you've added is too small to see any vertices. You can take a screenshot of Blender's window via the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add the link to your file into your question. It would also be useful to see Blender's full window which will show the outliner.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/interface/keymap/blender_default.html        in general, the whole problem was in switching the editing mode. I use ctrl + 2 to get the Subdivision modifier. While it's also a toggle for edit mode

Answer (score 1):

The whole problem was in switching to *Edit Mode*. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to get the Subdivision modifier. While it's also a toggle for *Edit Mode*.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/interface/keymap/blender_default.html

Comment: Sorry. I don't read Russian docs! :^) Glad to hear it's sorted.